# Removing string with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

My string as below;

> ... blablaa"}, "remove_list": [24, 20, 22, 25, 26, 23, 27, 19, 21], 
>   {"var": "value", ....

I have tried to remove string part as below, but nothing change

```
Regex.Replace(_QsString,@"""remove_list: [?+],", "");
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What exactly is the expected output?

Comment: Could you show the result you wish to obtain?

Comment: It looks like a JSON string. Why don't you just parse it and modify?

Comment: @ Gergo Erdosi Yes that is json, but i have to remove that part for my project flow.

Comment: @Gergo probably good way forward

Comment: @hwnd output should be ... blablaa"}, {"var": "value", ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me you are looking to replace everything between the square brackets including them and the preceding comma, your expression does not account for the double quotes after `remove_list` and `[?+]` is considered a character class; matching either a question mark or plus sign preferably "one" time.

I believe you are wanting the following instead ...

```
Regex.Replace(_QsString, @"""remove_list"": \[[^]]*],", "");
```

**Note**: To match a literal special character, you must precede it with a backslash outside of a character class.

[<kbd>**Code Demo**</kbd>](http://ideone.com/C8JVYI)

Answer (score 1):

What I think that you are trying to do with the `[?+]` part in the regular expression is to match whatever comes between `[` and `]`, but the syntax is wrong.

The expression `[?+]` will match the character `?` or the character `+`. The `[` and `]` becomes a set that matches any character inside it.

You need to escape the brackets and use the `.` selector instead of `?`. Also you should add another `?` after the qualifier to make it non-greedy, otherwise it will swallow everything up to the last `]` in the string:

```
Regex.Replace(_QsString,@"""remove_list"": \[.+?\],", "")
```

(Also, you were missing the closing quotation mark after `remove_list`.)

Comment: @Kerberos: Are you using the result of the expression? Strings are immutable in .NET so the `Replace` method can't change the original string, the result is returned as a new string.

Comment: @Guffa the actual string probably contains newline sequences, in this case without using the dotall modifier `(?s)` (forcing the dot to match newlines as well) the dot is limited to the same line